# dhall-to-yaml: How to consume args value into it

Tags: dhall

Context: I would like to create the template of service yaml config and pass corresponding parameter or argument to generate different app config file.

And the problem I got is how to pass the arg value into the dhall file and how to read the arg value from dhall file.

From my understanding, it would be something like **dhall-to-yaml --file service.dhall --key test --value "01"** but I do not sure how to give the command properly to pass and get the value from it.

Answer (score 2):

`dhall-to-yaml` accepts an arbitrary Dhall expression on standard input, so if you make your Dhall configuration file a function, like this:

```
λ(args : { test : Text }) → …
```

… then you can invoke the configuration file on that argument like this:

```
$ dhall-to-yaml <<< './config.dhall { test = "01" }'
```